# Infinispan start and stop scripts

Tags: distributed-caching, infinispan

In the Infinispan (v. 5.1.6 final) /bin directory there are scripts to start up the
Infinispan.

Why there is no scripts to stop it?

Is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> a legitimate way to stop Infinispan?

Answer (score 0):

There's no actual remote command to stop the cache (for security reasons), so it doesn't make sense having a script for it. Control+C would be the way to stop the standalone Infinispan server.